# GDAL Python on Webfaction

Tags: python, gdal, webfaction

I have GDAL installed on Webfaction wight the following commands:

```
$ mkdir src
$ cd scr
$ svn checkout https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/branches/1.10/gdal gdal
$ cd gdal
$ ./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 
$ make
$ make install
```

Now if I try to import GDAL I get the following error:

```
>>> from osgeo import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ustroetz/lib/python2.7/GDAL-1.10.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/ustroetz/lib/python2.7/GDAL-1.10.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /home/ustroetz/lib/python2.7/GDAL-1.10.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/_gdal.so: undefined symbol: GDALUseTransformer
```

However if cd to `lib`and try it there it works just fine:

```
>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>>
```

What do I have to set in order to use it from anywhere within Webfaction?

My lib folder contains the following:

```
$ ls
gdalplugins  libgdal.la  libgdal.so.1       python2.4  python2.7
libgdal.a    libgdal.so  libgdal.so.1.17.1  python2.5
```

Comment: Did you try python setup.py install?

Comment: No, do you have a link on how to do that with GDAL?

Comment: I found some info at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/

Comment: Yeah that is not so much helpful. I already have it installed. There is just something messed up with the paths.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with the following:

1. Open your `~/.bashrc`. You do this by typing in the command line:

   `$ vi ~/.bashrc`
2. Add to `~/.bashrc` the following:

   `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/your username/lib`
3. Close and save with

   `:x`
4. Restart the terminal.